# Copying Specific Cells From a Closed Workbook to My ActiveWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to open a closed workbook, copy cells G8, F8, E8, D8, C8, in that order to my ActiveWorkbook cells G8, G9, G10, G11, G12, in that order. Currently, I've written a code that will open the closed workbook copy cell G8 value and paste it to the activebook G8. This actually works, but my code is copying  data into cells other than G8.

How do I specifically only copy to these cells? Do I need to include `select` into my code?

```
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim vals As Variant


Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\x\xx\xx\Folder\File.xls")


Set y = ActiveWorkbook

vals = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G8").Value

y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G8").Value = vals


x.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It should be very fast, using arrays and working only in memory. Basically, it copies the range in discussion, which is contiguous and paste the reversed array:

```
Sub testCopyReversedRange()
 Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
 Dim arr As Variant, arrFin As Variant, i As Long, k As Long

 Set y = ActiveWorkbook: Set sh = y.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\x\xx\xx\Folder\File.xls")
 Set ws = x.Sheets("Sheet1")

 arr = sh.Range("C8:G8").Value
 ReDim arrFin(UBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 2), 1 To 1)
    
 For i = UBound(arr, 2) To 1 Step -1 'reverse the array order and transpose it
    k = k + 1
    arrFin(k, 1) = arr(1, i)
 Next i
 ws.Range("G8").Resize(UBound(arrFin, 1), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Edited:

And a even more compact version:

```
Sub testCopyReversedRangeBis()
 Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
 Dim arr As Variant, arrFin As Variant, I As Long, k As Long, vals As Variant

 Set y = ActiveWorkbook: Set sh = y.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\x\xx\xx\Folder\File.xls")
 Set ws = x.Sheets("Sheet1")
 arr = sh.Range("C8:G8").Value
 arrFin = Split(StrReverse(Join(Application.Index(arr, 1, 0), ",")), ",")

 ws.Range("G8").Resize(UBound(arrFin) + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrFin)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much this is perfect! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can customize this code by reading the comments and adjusting it to fit your needs:

```
Public Sub CopyCells()
    
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorkbookPath As String
    
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim counter As Long
    
    
    sourceWorkbookPath = "C:\x\xx\xx\Folder\File.xls"
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sourceWorkbookPath)
    
    Set targetWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    
    ' Dimension the array to the number of cells you're gonna copy
    Dim cellsToCopyConfig(4) As Variant
    
    ' Define the (source sheet and cell) and the (target sheet and cell)
    cellsToCopyConfig(0) = Array("Sheet1", "G8", "Sheet1", "G8")
    cellsToCopyConfig(1) = Array("Sheet1", "F8", "Sheet1", "G9")
    cellsToCopyConfig(2) = Array("Sheet1", "E8", "Sheet1", "G10")
    cellsToCopyConfig(3) = Array("Sheet1", "D8", "Sheet1", "G11")
    cellsToCopyConfig(4) = Array("Sheet1", "C8", "Sheet1", "G12")
    
    
    For counter = 0 To UBound(cellsToCopyConfig)
    
        sourceWorkbook.Sheets(cellsToCopyConfig(counter)(0)).Range(cellsToCopyConfig(counter)(1)).Copy _
            targetWorkbook.Sheets(cellsToCopyConfig(counter)(2)).Range(cellsToCopyConfig(counter)(3))
    
    Next counter
    
    sourceWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I really like this code, but I'm getting an error at `sourceWorkbook.Sheets(cellsToCopyConfig(counter)(0)).Range(cellsToCopyConfig(counter)(1)).Copy _
            targetWorkbook.Sheets(cellsToCopyConfig(counter)(2)).Range(cellsToCopyConfig(counter)(3))` the error reads Subscript out of bounds. I'm going to try to debug, but will send an update if I do.

Comment: This `Dim cellsToCopyConfig(4) as Variant` should match the number in the array assignment `cellsToCopyConfig(4) = Array(...` Check that and let me know

Answer (score 1):

You will want to avoid `select` at all costs. There are probably more efficient ways to go about this, but this is a really simple one that you can follow along with

```
Dim new_wb as Workbook, old_wb as Workbook
Dim new_ws as Worksheet, old_ws as Worksheet
Dim i as Long
Dim new_Cells as Variant, old_Cells as Variant

'set where you want the cells to go in the new workbook
new_Cells = Array("G8", "G9", "G10", "G11", "G12")

'now set where the old cells you want to match up are
old_Cells = Array ("G8, "F8, "E8", "D8", "C8")

'set your active workbook first, that way your computer doesn't confuse the one you will open soon
Set new_wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set new_ws = new_wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

'now open and set your other workbook
Set old_wb = Workbooks.Open('yourpath')
Set old_ws = old_wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Loop through where you want the new cells, and put the old cells in that spot. Notice we change the array we use between the new workbook and the old one
For i = LBound(new_Cells) to UBound(new_Cells)
    new_ws.Range(new_Cells(i)).value = old_ws.Range(old_Cells(i)).value
Next i

old_wb.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If there are only 5 cells I hardly can see any reason to use tables, loops etc.
2. The target cells make a contigous range, so if you decide to use loop there is no need to prepare an array with the ranges, better simply put the loop index into offset or use a table for values and after completing them copy the contents into the target range.

Answer (score 0):

One of a few ways to read data from closed workbooks without opening them is using the **ExecuteExcel4Macro** function:

- You need to use R1C1 reference style
- You can't utilize **UsedRange** and all its benefits as you can only evaluate each cell individually
- File and sheet name encapsulated in apostrophe
- Actual workbook name encapsulated in brackets
- Then, use "!" to indicate external reference

Knowing the workbook and sheet name, you can set it up as follows (tested and works!):

```
ExecuteExcel4Macro("'C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\[test read.xlsb]Sheet1'!R1C1")
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to open the workbook you can try this

```
Sub UpdateData()
    Dim cl As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G8:G12")
        For Each cl In .Cells
            cl.Formula = "='C:\x\xx\xx\Folder\[File.xls]Sheet1'!" & Chr(79 - cl.Row) & "8"
        Next cl
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

This took 0.14 seconds to run in my computer.

**Edit:** (following comments)

```
Chr(71) = "G"
Chr(70) = "F"
Chr(69) = "E"
Chr(68) = "D"
Chr(67) = "C"

So you need to map
Row ->  Letter ascii Code ->   Chr(79 - cl.Row) & "8"
8   ->  71 = 79 - 8       ->   G8
9   ->  70 = 79 - 9       ->   F8
10  ->  69 = 79 - 10      ->   E8
11  ->  68 = 79 - 11      ->   D8
12  ->  67 = 79 - 12      ->   C8

Hope this clarifies the formula
```

Comment: This is a really cool way to do this! Can you briefly describe the processes of the `& Chr(79 - cl.Row) & 8`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! That really helps! I didn't realize the numbers I was copying were in millions. If I want to show these numbers in 1000s can I simply add a `/1000` within the `cl.Formula` code? I haven't necessarily found were I can put it. When I try it errors out, but was just wondering if this is the appropriate place to include this.

Comment: If you want to divide by 1000 try `"='C:\x\xx\xx\Folder\[File.xls]Sheet1'!" & Chr(79 - cl.Row) & "8/1000"`

Comment: I would suggest you comment out the line `.Value = .Value` so that you see the generated formulae and manipulate them appropriately. Once you're happy with your formulae, reinstate the commented line to remove the formulae after copying the data.